# param is missing or the value is empty: register

Tags: ruby-on-rails

routes.rb is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    devise_for :heads
    resources :events do
        resources :registers
    end
    root 'events#index'
end
```

register.rb controller is

```
class RegistersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :register_params,only: [:create]

    def create
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @register = @event.registers.new(register_params)
        @register.user = current_user

        respond_to do |format|
            if @register.save
                format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render json: @register, status: :created, location: @register }
            else
                format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.json { render json: @register.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end


    private

    def register_params
        params.require(:register).permit(:event_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

I am trying to make a web app in which heads can create an event ans users can  come up and register gotr those events....

Please reply as soon as possible.....

Heads can create events
while users can register for those events...

Comment: first thing--you have the resources nested inside events...take them out. You don't need to nest this if it's only a create action.

Comment: Can you include the view including the form as well?

Comment: On taking resources out  of nested events giving error ->  undefined method `event_registers_path'